# How can I improve the topology of this model?

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm trying to learn topology by modeling the Logitech G600. I started with the top cover, but even at the 2nd try, I still find my topology a little bit messy. I feel the most difficult aspect lies in the two big holes (covered by red lines) representing the mouse wheel and the two extra buttons. It requires more vertices at the edges to smooth it out, thereby rendering the topology messy. How can I improve the topology of this model?

Thank you.

Blender file: [Logitech G600 Model](https://gofile.io/?c=7H0Xv0)

[image: My model]

Answer (score 2):

Adding new verticies correctly with the knife tool will sharpen the edges where required.

Convex corners

See attached (white): X and dissolve the edge but not the vertex (uncheck this option in dissolve edges property box when it appears).

Concave corners

See attached (red): Cut in the yellow and remove the blue to provide supporting eges.

Knife cut the new verts/edge which will remain as quads not ngons

You will see that the corner is sharp and the sub-d has smoothed the object.

[image]

For the central hole I would set it up as;

[image]

For the part you have circled I would work like this:

[image]

Everyone does stuff differently this is just my solution

Here it is under 2 subdivisions

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Barkest! Would you mind explaining how I should change the topology connected to the parts covered by the red lines? It looks messy there. Should I use the same approach suggested to those corners?

Comment: See original answer for solution. Note that all faces are quads so where you see the convex corner in the last image it has a vert right on the corner which allows it to hold its shape and creates a quad

Comment: Wow, look like the problem has been fully solved. I'll try to model it tomorrow to see how it works out. Thanks a ton, Barkest. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi Barkest, would you mind sending me your blender file so that I can closely study them?

Comment: Sorry, I made it then deleted it. It was only the parts shown in the images.

Comment: I've followed along and made this: https://ibb.co/fMVrjVd. The sides have many vertices, making the topology in the two left click/right click area messy. Can you give me any tips to solve that problem? I apologize if my questions are so basic. I'm trying to understand topology.

Comment: Its improving :) I would recommend this https://topologyguides.com/ good luck

Comment: Thanks a ton, friend. I think I quite figure how to solve it. Guess I'll direct those vertices towards the bottom or other areas of the mouse rather than towards the far left side.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing ctrl+r and creating new loop-cuts on every edge you could use the knife tool to add the new vertices where you want them without messing with the whole mesh 
knife tool shot cut: k 
for locking the knife tool at certain angles press c

Comment: it's tedious but it's a way to get what you want

Comment: Adding new vertices without adding loop cuts will create n-gons. Aren't they something we should avoid? That's the reason I use loop cut instead of knife tool in the first place